# Abp framework : An error occurred during the initialize, after switching from EF Core SqlServer to EF Core PostgreSQL Provider

Tags: .net, abp, dbmigrator

I'm using abp framework and after switching from EF Core SqlServer to EF Core PostgreSQL Provider during the project, I get the following error when I run the DbMigrator or Host projects. Can someone help me with this ?

The problem is in one of the framework proper methods.
I tried restoring packages cleaning and rebuild the solution, I also deleted all local packages from "C:\Users[Username].nuget\packages", to reload them from remote repos.

```
Unhandled exception. Volo.Abp.AbpInitializationException: An error occurred during the initialize Volo.Abp.Modularity.OnApplicationInitializationModuleLifecycleContributor phase of the module Volo.Abp.BackgroundJobs.AbpBackgroundJobsModule, Volo.Abp.BackgroundJobs, Version=5.3.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null: Method not found: 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1<Volo.Abp.ApplicationInitializationContext> Volo.Abp.BackgroundWorkers.BackgroundWorkersApplicationInitializationContextExtensions.AddBackgroundWorkerAsync(Volo.Abp.ApplicationInitializationContext)'.. See the inner exception for details.
 ---> System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1<Volo.Abp.ApplicationInitializationContext> Volo.Abp.BackgroundWorkers.BackgroundWorkersApplicationInitializationContextExtensions.AddBackgroundWorkerAsync(Volo.Abp.ApplicationInitializationContext)'.
   at Volo.Abp.BackgroundJobs.AbpBackgroundJobsModule.OnApplicationInitializationAsync(ApplicationInitializationContext context)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.Start[TStateMachine](TStateMachine& stateMachine)
   at Volo.Abp.BackgroundJobs.AbpBackgroundJobsModule.OnApplicationInitializationAsync(ApplicationInitializationContext context)
   at Volo.Abp.Modularity.OnApplicationInitializationModuleLifecycleContributor.InitializeAsync(ApplicationInitializationContext context, IAbpModule module)
   at Volo.Abp.Modularity.ModuleManager.InitializeModulesAsync(ApplicationInitializationContext context)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Volo.Abp.Modularity.ModuleManager.InitializeModulesAsync(ApplicationInitializationContext context)
   at Volo.Abp.AbpApplicationBase.InitializeModulesAsync()
   at Volo.Abp.AbpApplicationWithInternalServiceProvider.InitializeAsync()
   at UMAR.DbMigrator.DbMigratorHostedService.StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken) in C:\Users\ERRAFIQI\Documents\Repos\umar-api-postgresql\umar-api\src\UMAR.DbMigrator\DbMigratorHostedService.cs:line 32
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Internal.Host.StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.RunAsync(IHost host, CancellationToken token)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.RunAsync(IHost host, CancellationToken token)
   at UMAR.DbMigrator.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\ERRAFIQI\Documents\Repos\umar-api-postgresql\umar-api\src\UMAR.DbMigrator\Program.cs:line 30
   at UMAR.DbMigrator.Program.<Main>(String[] args)
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you check this:

**In `EntityFrameworkCore` project**

- In `UMARDbContextFactory`, line 20:

```cs
    var builder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<UMARDbContext>()
            .UseNpgSql(configuration.GetConnectionString("Default"));
```

- In `UMAREntityFrameworkCoreModule`

```cs
        Configure<AbpDbContextOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.UseNpgSql();
        });
```

**In `HttpApi.Host` project**

- In Program class, add:

```cs
    AppContext.SetSwitch("Npgsql.EnableLegacyTimestampBehavior", true);
```

Before: `Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()`

Note: Check also all appsettings file configuration, in `DbMigrator` and `HttpApi.Host` projects

Comment: Thank u for your response, but :
I already changed the package and change the methoses from UseSqlmServer to UseNpgSql in both of UMARDbContextFactory and UMAREntityFrameworkCoreModule.
I also already added AppContext.SetSwitch(...); in both of Migrator and Host projects, that EntityFramework or PostgreSql accept mapping my fields of type DateTime.
But the problem i got is before trying to map or connect the daba base, it's in the initialisation of the application. 
I also checked the configs are right.
I can upload my project if you want to test at your own !

Comment: Yes, it can still help to solve the problem.
But I wonder if the problem is just the BackgroundJob module and not a migration problem. Perhaps in `UMARDbMigratorModule` file, try to comment this line `Configure<AbpBackgroundJobOptions>(options => options.IsJobExecutionEnabled = false);` (and others references at this module)